# Java bad operand types of binary '&&'

Tags: java, instance

Trying to compile this code that originally worked but doesn't seem to anymore.

```
if (book instanceof STLoanBook && (STLoanBook)book.reserve(reserverID)) {
```

I'm trying to call book.reserve which is only apart of STLoanBook. If I remove the type then it will error stating there is no symbol. How do I fix this?

```
Assignment 3>javac *.java
LibrarySystem.java:334: error: cannot find symbol
      if (book instanceof STLoanBook && book.reserve(reserverID)) {
                                            ^
symbol:   method reserve(String)
location: variable book of type LoanBook
1 error

Assignment 3>javac *.java
LibrarySystem.java:334: error: cannot find symbol
      if (book instanceof STLoanBook && (STLoanBook)book.reserve(reserverID)
){
                                                        ^

symbol:   method reserve(String)
location: variable book of type LoanBook
LibrarySystem.java:334: error: bad operand types for binary operator '&&'
      if (book instanceof STLoanBook && (STLoanBook)book.reserve(reserverID)
) {
                                     ^
first type:  boolean
second type: STLoanBook
2 errors
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing parentheses:

```
((STLoanBook)book).reserve(reserverID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use another pair of parantheses:

```
if (book instanceof STLoanBook && ((STLoanBook) book).reserve(reserverID)) { ... }
```

Now the expression `((STLoanBook) book)` is of the requested type - `STLoanBook`.